# ReactNative - get values from redux-form

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form

I use ReactNative + redux + redux-form.

In my login.js screen, I have this :

```
function bindAction(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(loginActions, dispatch)
    };
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state.loginReducer
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(reduxForm({
    form: "login",
    initialValues: {
        email: "test@test.fr",
        password: "123123"
    }
})(LoginForm));
```

And my form is :

```
<Field
    name="email"
    component={this.renderInput}
    type="email"
    validate={[email, required]}
/>
<Field
    name="password"
    component={this.renderInput}
    type="password"
    validate={[minLength6, maxLength15, required]}
/>
```

I want to call the function `login()` with the values of my fields.

I tried :

```
login() {
    if (this.props.valid) {
        this.props.actions.loginUser(selector(this.state, 'email', 'password'));
    }
}
```

With :

```
const selector = formValueSelector("login")
```

I have no errors, but my fields are always empty in the `login()` function.

To be honest, I read the doc, but I am not sure how to use correctly redux-form. I need to use something else to get the field value ? Thanks.

** **EDIT** **

Regarding to some examples, I use now this code :

```
<Button
    style={styles.loginBtn}
    disabled={this.props.loading}
    onPress={handleSubmit(this.login)}
>
...
</Button>
```

And now, I can access form data in my function :

```
login(data) {
    if (this.props.valid) {
        this.props.actions.loginUser({
            username: data.email, 
            password: data.password
        });
         ....
```

I don't know if it is the correct way, in react-native, I didn't find any example using `<form>` elements, but it works.

Comment: Is the login function called on form submit?

Comment: I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

In the redux-form you can either use the [`handleSubmit`](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/faq/handlevson.md/) function to pass the values to your handler *the form is valid*, or use [`formValueSelector`](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.14/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/), to get the form values

**handleSubmit**

```
<Button
    style={styles.loginBtn}
    disabled={loading || !valid || pristine}
    onPress={handleSubmit(this.login)}
>
...
</Button>

login(data) {
  this.props.actions.loginUser({
    username: data.email,
    password: data.password
  });
}
```

**formValueSelector**

```
const LoginForm = reduxForm({ // <== const Form Handler
  form: 'login', // <== Your Redux Form name
  initialValues: {
    email: "test@test.fr",
    password: "123123"
  }
})(Login); // <== Bind your Class Name here

const selector = formValueSelector('login') // <== Redux Form Name

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  email: selector(state, 'email'),
  password: selector(state, 'password'),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm); // <== Bind the const Form Handler
```

and then access it in your props via `const {email, password} = this.props`

Comment: Thanks, this is why I saw on doc, but how to combine this with a reducer ? I have a reducer (loginReducer), and I don't know how to combine in the `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: If your loginReducer contains fields as `email` and `password` , then you can return merge the fields inside `mapStateToProps` as `const {email , password} = selector(state, 'email', 'password')` and return it  as `loginReducer: {...state.loginReducer, email, password}`